# Android touch event from background service

Tags: java, android, scroll, simulation

I would like to generate a scroll event when input is received from an external device connected to Android. Upon receiving the input I would like to call something that either scrolls up or down. I've already taken care of the I/O and now just need to simulate the scroll. Also, this is a service that runs in the background so the scrolling would need to be simulated on whatever is on screen. This is why I thought simulating a touch event would work.

I've been looking at `TouchUtils`. I'm having doubts because this seems primarily to be used for testing. My application isn't for a test or anything, but rather something that will be permanently connected. Is this the best way to go about doing it? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //do some UI stuff here

    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is super un-clear.
any way i would suggest you investigate `Instrumentation` class.
for example:

```
Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
m_Instrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 100, 400, 0));
```

check out [this cool article](https://www.pocketmagic.net/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/) for more